# Automatically create an invoice with customer details from website

Tags: javascript, automation

I've just set up a website with much help from this site!

I have customers who buy items (through the PayPal interface that takes care of the credit card payments).

I have made invoices in LaTex, which I edit manually. The next step I want to take, is to learn how to get my website to pass the purchase information into my LaTex document so that the invoice is automatically generated, and automatically send a copy to the customer.

My question is just: what things should I be searching for to look in order to learn about this kind of thing? I don't know where to start. Would it be JavaScript that would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need a backend language for that like NodeJS, PHP, Java etc.

Where i would start is look at the documentation of LaTex and see if they have API's to hook into to do what you want to do and go from there.

Usually if there are api's available they will come with examples to get you started.